# EditText - Gap between text and EditText's line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

When I insert text to my `EditText` field the text has an abnormal gap between itself and the `EditText`'s line. Here's a printscreen from my terminal where you can see this gap I'm talking about, it is marked in red.
[image]

I've played around with text alignment and gravity but to no success.

Here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/startJourneyLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startLocationTxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:text="@string/startLocation"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/startLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:gravity = "bottom"
                android:hint="Some text"
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:src="@drawable/my_ic_location"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/endLocationTxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/endLocation"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/endLocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:inputType="text"/>
        </TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/go"/>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone spot why this is happening and explain me how can I fix it?

**--------------- EDIT -----------------------**

I've updated the XML code I posted in the original question to the real XML code I've on my app as requested in a comment.

The first printscreen (the one above, is from a real device -> Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.4 CyanogenMod) and here is a printscreen from the emulator using API 19

[image]

Comment: is that green line is a custom image?

Comment: No, it's the `EditText`'s line when you are typing some text into it.

Comment: its working fine in my end..hav u added any code for it for allignment?

Comment: No, I didn't. All the layout code is on that `xml`file. Weird it is working on your device because on mine it is just like on the image I posted in the question.

Comment: This should work fine. This happens usually in the emulator/preview in Android Studio....in practice, it doesn't actually do that. If you have access to another device, try it there

Comment: @AlexK I'm testing in a real device. That image is from a Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.4 CyanogenMod.

Comment: post a xml code which u r running pls...

Comment: You haven't given any padding in `EditText` even though it shows space between bottom line and text!!! I guess it's because you have used `TableLayout`. Why do you use it? `RelativeLoyout` or `LnearLayout` are strong enough to make this kinda design. I suggest you not to use `TableLayout`.

Comment: use this line and try `android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"`..

Comment: @MSGadag in the `EditText`? If so, it didn't help too.

Answer (score 39):

To change gap between `EditText` text and bottom line you can use [`android:paddingBottom`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingBottom)

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
     style="@style/DarkEditText"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/name"
     android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
```

Replace `paddingBottom` value as per your requirement. Or you can use `android:paddingTop`

Comment: In my case increasing `android:paddingTop` was the correct way to go.

Answer (score 2):

**Try**

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**instead of**

`android:layout_height="match_parent"` on your EditText.

Comment: Not me who downvoted you but both my `EditText` are `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding to edit text

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:hint="Hint"/>
```